# Javafx 8 - setVisible() is blocked

Tags: javafx-8

So here is my situation:
I have built a GUI using the scene Builder and it works just fine: A search box and a list. When the user search a value the results are correctly displayed on the list.

What I've tried to do is to add a progress bar to be showed when the user makes a search. For that I have added a pane to be used as a wrapper and inside the pane there is the progress bar.

On the controller initialization I do a:

```
progressBarWrapper.setVisible(false)
```

which works. When I try to activate it inside the search it doesn't:

```
 private void search() {
        progressBarWrapper.setVisible(true);
        String val = searchField.getText();

        if (val!= null && !"".equals(val)) {
            ObjectList list = service.getObjects(val);

            objects.clear();
            objects.addAll(list);
        }
        progressBarWrapper.setVisible(false);
    }
```

what I've realized is that if I remove the bottom line where the wrapper is set to invisible again I do get my progress bar to show up, however only when I already have the results.

I guess this is some kind of blocking issue or the redraw process of the screen beeing held back while computations are beeing made, however I don't understand what is going on... can somebody shed a light on it so I can develop it further? Just explain why this behaviour happens so I can have an idea on how to solve it.

Thanks

EDIT: Here I am adding a SSCCE to exemplify

Main.java

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("Main.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            Scene primaryScene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(primaryScene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

In the controller I have simulated the getting of data through a simple loop with a thread sleep inside.
MainController.java

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private Button startLoop;

    @FXML
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @FXML
    private Pane progressBarWrapper;

    @FXML
    private Label loopCounter;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Application Started");

        progressBarWrapper.setVisible(false);
    }

    @FXML
    private void doLoop() {
        progressBarWrapper.setVisible(true);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            progressBar.setProgress(i * 0.2);
            loopCounter.setText(String.format("%s loop(s)", i));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // 1000 milliseconds is one second.
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }

        progressBarWrapper.setVisible(false);
    }

}
```

And the View:
Main.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="startLoop" layoutX="258.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doLoop" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="84.0" text="START LOOP" />
      <Label fx:id="loopCounter" layoutX="286.0" layoutY="165.0" text="0">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="48.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Pane fx:id="progressBarWrapper" layoutX="461.0" layoutY="297.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <ProgressBar fx:id="progressBar" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="191.0" prefWidth="200.0" progress="0.0">
               <cursor>
                  <Cursor fx:constant="WAIT" />
               </cursor>
            </ProgressBar>
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

All is simply under a package called "application"

Comment: please provide a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: There you go! Thanks for helping @kleopatra

Comment: whatever you do, you must not sleep on the fx-thread!

Comment: sorry, it was the quickiest way I though to simulate some action, but you are right. On my original situation a have a URL request and subsequent DOM parsing using Jsoup. Can you offer me some advice on how to write an example here that would also cost some time and would exemplify my waiting in the real application?

Comment: I believe that this can be a solution to my problem right? https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

Comment: Thanks so much for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During some help by the user **kleopatra** in the comments I came accross the following link from oracle:

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

Basically my problem sums up to the following:

> The JavaFX scene graph, which represents the graphical user interface
>   of a JavaFX application, is not thread-safe and can only be accessed
>   and modified from the UI thread also known as the JavaFX Application
>   thread. **Implementing long-running tasks on the JavaFX Application
>   thread inevitably makes an application UI unresponsive**. A best
>   practice is to do these tasks on one or more background threads and
>   let the JavaFX Application thread process user events.

Hope it helps someone!